# Praat exporting Textgrid script to csv

Tags: praat, annotation

I have a praat script with codes written to analyze/export a TextGrid file to csv. But when I try to run the script and analyze the TextGrid file with the pre-coded praat script, it exports an incomplete csv. file (i.e. it has all the columns labeled correctly, but doesn't actually have the details/data about the annotations). I'm not sure if it's because of the way I'm exporting or running the program, but any help or insight would be very much appreciated!